# Windows or Linux programmatically add sound output and interact with it

Tags: linux, windows, audio

I am working on a project where I want to get all of the sound output from the computer, In windows you can go to the audio output and choose what device you want to send the audio to Ex. Headphones Speaker Monitor. I want to add my own device to this list and be able to access the audio. I don't expect anyone to know exactly how to do this but if anyone has any documentation that would be useful.

Comment: I would prefer if possible information on linux as linux is open source and generally runs better than windows performance wise.

Comment: For Linux, you can find informations on https://alsa-project.org/wiki/Main_Page and https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/

Comment: @Fryz On first glance PulseAudio Seems to be exactly what I was looking for I will have to read the documentation.

Comment: your ears should ring with you come across something called `audio loopback`

Comment: @ScottStensland Yes I know about that, I do not plan to play the audio at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pulseaudio command shown in this github issue which remaps the output to act as a microphone input. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/32299

```
pactl load-module module-remap-source master="$(pactl list | grep -A2 '^Source #' |  grep 'Name: .*\.monitor$' | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n1)" source_name=virtmic source_properties=device.description=Virtual_Microphone
```